# Authentication for Dynamics CRM 2015 (On Premise) SOAP services without ADFS

Tags: soap-client, adfs, dynamics-crm-2015

I know there are quite a few posts on trying to connect to Dynamics CRM already but I haven't found a definitive answer yet. So here goes:

Environment:

- Microsoft Dynamics 2015 *On-Premise*
- Java SOAP client, running outside of the Windows Domain (not sure if that's
  relevant)

Although quite old I think [this is the most helpful blogpost](http://leandrob.com/2012/02/request-a-token-from-adfs-using-ws-trust-from-ios-objective-c-iphone-ipad-android-java-node-js-or-any-platform-or-language/) that I could find about connecting to an On-Premise CRM. However it assumes that there is an ADFS server that I can talk to to get a security token based on a username/password combination. At the moment we don't have an ADFS server present here.

My question is can I use a different way of authenticating for the CRM SOAP services? Or do I have to have a ADFS server present?

Comment: Download the soapui and connect to the api you want to use, IIRC you should get a wsdl which you can adjust to do stuff which will show you how to connect.

Comment: no it didn't, Bad memory

Comment: Hi again, I just saw that the soap client is running outside the domain, can you connect to the CRM from that computer running it in a web browser?

Comment: Yes I have no problem connecting via a web browser. I have tried to use SOAP-UI with different kinds of authentication (BASIC, NTLM/SPNego) but that doesn't seem to work. I don't seem to know exactly what I should configure for NTLM for example, and just BASIC authentication doesn't work.

Comment: Tricky, I've used SOAP-ui to test stuff but I think I've logged in to the server using some logon-thingy in soap-ui. Sorry, can't think of any solution atm. This blog might point you in some direction, it's perl but the xml should be the same http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1077118

Answer (score 1):

Without ADFS the only other option is Active Directory authentication typically set to use NTLM on the web server (see scheme here: http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html). Typically, NTLM is handled in HTTP libraries via a proxy such as in CURL or .NET. For Java, you should be able to use the NTLM support in HttpClient (https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/ntlm.html). NTLM is very chatty in terms of the back and forth described in the scheme link above. But as long as your HTTP library supports it, it should be somewhat seamless to you from a usage standpoint.

Below is an example calling the OrganizationData.svc using curl+NTLM with PHP. The process is the same for the SOAP Organization.svc. You would just include the SOAP body and the `SOAPAction` header such as `http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Execute`.

```php
// The host name of the on-premises dynamics instance
$host = 'crm.mycompany.com';
$organization = 'MyCompany';
$crm_url = "http://$host/$organization/";

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$url = $crm_url . 'XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/SystemUserSet';
$ch = curl_init();
 $headers = array(
      'Method: GET',
      'Connection: keep-alive',
      'User-Agent: PHP-SOAP-CURL',
      'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'Accept: application/json',
      'Host: ' . $host);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$response=json_decode($response, true);

print_r($response);
```

Here are a couple of options for NTLM libs for java:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/ntlmv2auth/
- https://jcifs.samba.org/

Comment: Hi, which username and password to give? Is it the credential that we use to to log into dynamics crm?

Comment: Yes, you just use the credentials (username and password) you use to login to Dynamics. Username is typically in the username@domain.com or domain\username format.

Comment: This answer is quite old.Does it still work on version dynamics crm 9

Comment: Yes, still works on v9